# mv command deleted a folder

Tags: command-line, mv

I am new to linux. I had a folder called "Código" where I kept all of my .h's and .cpp's when I programmed. I wanted to move said folder up one directory and into a new folder called "Code", so in the terminal I typed the following:

```
mv ./Código ..-Code
```

Of course, I meant to type:

```
mv ./Código ../Code
```

But I forgot that my keyboard was in spanish mode. Now my "Código" folder does not exist. I cant find it with any searches of my file system. I tried cd-ing to "..-Code", "-Code", and ".-Code" and it didn't like that... Can anyone tell me what exactly happened to my folder, and if it's contents are recoverable (without some disk recovery utility)?

I already looked at the man page and did some basic googling but found nothing useful. Wasn't really even sure what to google...

Comment: I did that and I get a folder called `..-Code` in the same folder where `Codigo` was. The folder name starts with a dot so it is a hidden folder, execute `ls -lah` and look if it appears. Also, in nautilus (the ubuntu file manager) you can show hidden files by pressing `Ctrl+H`

Comment: @Zanna Done! :)

Comment: Yeah, woa, sorry for taking so long to do that... Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I followed your instructions :)

I mean, I created a folder called `Código/` and then I executed the same (wrong) command.

What happened was that the folder `Código/` was renamed to `..-Code/`. The name of the folder starts with a dot (`.`) so it is now a hidden folder.

Now if you execute `ls -a` in your terminal, then the folder `..-Code/` should appear (as will every hidden file in the directory).

You can also see hidden files using Nautilus (the Ubuntu file manager) by pressing `Ctrl+H`.

**EDIT**: in order to recover ('un-hide') the folder you just need to execute `mv ..-Code ./Code` and you'll have the folder named like you wanted.

Comment: Maybe add how to "un-hide" files by renaming it to `Code/`?